# With Auto Route, How to pass args with nested route?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-routes

- For example, how to pass args to SettingsPage or PostsPage?

```dart
AutoRoute(              
      path: '/',              
      page: EmptyPageRoute,              
      children: [              
        AutoRoute(path: 'users', page: UsersPage),              
        AutoRoute(path: 'posts', page: PostsPage),          
        AutoRoute(path: 'settings', page: SettingsPage),                
      ],              
    ),
```

- What is the best practise?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to achieve this:

```dart
context.routeData.inheritedPathParams.getString('key');
```

This is most versatile way to grab your path parameter.

```dart
context.router.routeData.pathParams.getString('key');
context.router.routeData.queryParams.getString('key');
```

I use this most of the time, useful for sub routes those have common identity.

```dart
context.routeData.parent?.pathParams.getString('key');
context.routeData.parent?.queryParams.getString('key');
```

Simply gets from the parent directly if exists.

I usually prefer first two methods. They are more assuring and null-safe.